# Android SDK Manager not showing any packages to install

Tags: android

I'm having a problem in the Android SDK Manager in which it doesn't show that I have any packages available to install:

[image: SDK PM]

When I first installed the SDK, the only line I saw there was the Android SDK Tools. I was able to add the Platform-Tools and Android 4.2 package my copying and pasting from the Android ADT bundle that I downloaded separately.

The log is showing no issues:

```
Fetching https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml
Fetched Add-ons List successfully
Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-7.xml
Done loading packages.
```

And I can see available packages when I open up the XML the package URL returns.

Things I've tried:
1. Messing with the proxy in Tools > Options. I've tried both 127.0.0.1 and blank.
2. Opening the SDK Manager from Eclipse and directly (regular and as Administrator)
3. Uninstalling and re-installing the Android SDK. Downloading the latest versions of everything.

My system:
Windows 7 x64
Eclipse 4.2.1 Juno
SDK Manager 21.1
ADT 21.1

Any ideas? I suppose I could download the files by pulling URLs directly from the XML, but that isn't ideal.

**Edit:**

Since I can pull the repository-7.xml file using a browser, this doesn't look like a Firewall/AV/Network setup issue. It's a matter of the SDK Manager not loading up the package information it pulls back through the XML.

Comment: does your machines belong to a network? If it is you have to set proxy , workstation , domain stuff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I was finally able to see all of the available packages. I accidentally hit the SDK Manager icon in Eclipse instead of the AVD Manager I meant to press:

[image: Eclipse]

And all of the available packages showed up.

Also, now when I open the SDK Manager using any of the other methods (directly from SDK directory or using the Window > Android SDK Manager menu option in Eclipse) all of those missing packages are now showing up.

Answer (score 12):

I got the same problem. For me the solution was putting a check on the "Force https://... sources to be fetched using http://..." box. It's on Android SDK Manager's preferences screen, below the proxy settings.

Also if this doesn't solve your problem, instead of downloading SDK again, I suggest you to download the [Adt Bundle](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html)

Comment: I've tried checking/unchecking all of the options in the Options screen. The only effect the Force https://... has is taking longer to not return any updates. I have downloaded the ADT bundle, but I'd like to get this working with my current version of Eclipse.

Comment: One last suggestion, close firewall & anti-virus. According to some posts, that "magically" solves the problem.

Comment: Switch to https, then reload, install SDK tools & platform tools. Close the SDK manager, then open it fresh. This worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

i had the same problem.
and nothing works for me, nor clearing cache, nor restart eclipse, nor running sdk manager from eclipse, nor forcing https (from sdk manager options)

but every thing works fine when i used proxy!!
sdk manager-> tools-> options -> http proxy server

Comment: set proxy on automatically and use a proxy software.

Answer (score 2):

I know that I'm kind of late to the party, But I wanted to share my experience with this issue.

It turned out that the underlying Logger module used was the SL4J Android edition. Because I had overridden the version (using an external JAR file) that the SDK Manager used, a lot of things went wrong when it tried to load the Logger class. I discovered this when i tried to run

android-sdk\tools\android.bat update sdk --no-ui

which showed me an exception thrown by the ClassLoader of the logger module. Removing every trace I had of the SL4J modules in my %JAVA_HOME%\jre\lib\ext folder solved ALL of my problems.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but just wanted to add for posterity.  I had this same problem and it turns out I had previously ran the SDK Manager as root (Ubuntu Linux).  My user account didn't have permissions to overwrite the files and update the list.  Once I corrected the permissions, it ran fine.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, if you are running the SDK Manager directly from `~Android\android-sdk` directory, just right click and Run as administrator. That did the trick for me anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Are you opening the Adroid SDK when you unzipped the folder downloaded?. Becouse i had a problem like you, and the solution was that i am taking a wrong folder path.

What i did:

- Downloaded again the sdk and put it in C:/ (Another Path)
- Check in this path if i get the same result.
- install the new tools and android version from the new path.

becouse i see that u have your folder in C:/ProgramFile/Android......... and i have in this path only that i have installed.

Comment: I tried uninstalling and then installing in a different directory (C:\Android\android-sdk\) and am experiencing the same issues.

Answer (score 0):

Open Android SDKManager->Android SDK->SDK Update Site
Click on Launch Standalone Android SDK Manager you will see the packages.

Answer (score 0):

On SDK manager go to tools -> options and select force https checkbox; now you should see all